# use via with many to many relationship in yii framework

Tags: activerecord, yii2, many-to-many

I'm struggling a bit with yii.
I currently trying to show data with many-to-many relationships.

I have:

```
table set
name
description

table item 
name
description

table subinventory
name
description

and table setDetail who link them all
set_id
item_id
subinventory_id
```

I generated a crud for Set and added a Gridview to show all the items present in the set (saved in the setDetail table)
the dataprovider is this one

```
$dataProvider= new ActiveDataProvider(
          [ 'query' => $this->hasMany(SetDetail::className(), ['set_id' => 'id'])
        ]
```

Its work well but of course it show the ID of the item and subinventory.
I can retrieve the data in the gridview but it'll make a request for each one which is not ideal I think.

I wanted to do a viaTable like that:

```
$dataProvider= new ActiveDataProvider(
              [ 'query' => $this->hasMany(SetDetail::className(), ['set_id' => 'id'])->viaTable('item',['id => 'item_id'])
            ]
```

But it don't work obviously because item_id is not in set table but in setDetail table.

So my question: Is there a way to properly (I mean using the yii framework) using viaTable with data provided by query ?
I'm surely not really clear so don't hesitate to correct me

Here the generated relation inside setDetail model.

```
  /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getItem()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getReason()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Reason::className(), ['id' => 'reason_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getReference()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Reference::className(), ['id' => 'reference_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSet()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Set::className(), ['id' => 'set_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSubinventory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Subinventory::className(), ['id' => 'subinventory_id']);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `Set`Model to create dataProvider? then add `SetDetail` model with all relation in it.

Comment: @InsaneSkull yes, I create the dataprovider inside Set model. I'm pretty sure I'm messing with it and there is a way better method to do this. Plus I maybe did'nt done the database correctly with what I want to achieve

Comment: damn, I juste tested something without conviction and its working…

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, mainly because I ask before really searching…

I wanted to use via but a leftJoin was what I needed. Plus I tested simply put `database.column` and its working. So my code is like that.

```
  $dataProvider= new ActiveDataProvider(
      [ 'query' => $this->hasMany(SetDetail::className(), ['set_id' => 'id'])
    ->leftJoin('item','`item`.`id` = `setDetail`.`item_id`')
    ->leftJoin('subinventory','`subinventory`.`id` = `setDetail`.`subinventory_id`')
    ->select([
      "`setDetail`.*",
      "`item`.name AS item_name",
      "`subinventory`.name AS subinventory_name",
    ])
      ]
    );
```

and I also need to add the subinventory_name and item_name in SetDetail model :

```
class SetDetail extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  public $item_name;
  public $subinventory_name;
…
```

Comment: No need to do this, add your `setDetail` model and i will add a better solution.

Comment: What do you need exactly ? the entire setDetail model file ?

Comment: @InsaneSkull thats what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$dataProvider= new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Set::find()->with(['setDetails.item', 'setDetails.subinventory'])->where(['id' => $id]);
]);
```

Here, `setDetails` is whatever your hasMany relation name in `Set` model.

**For View**

```
$model = Set::find()
   ->with(['setDetails.item', 'setDetails.subinventory'])
   ->where(['id' => $id])
   ->one();
```

Use foreach on `setDetails` to display every SetDetail model.

Comment: There is no where condition in your request ?

Comment: @eephyne why you need where?

Comment: I probably explained really badly my situation. Imagine the following scenario: I go to the list of set, I choose one of them and go to the /set/view?id=X. In the view page I want to show All the setDetail row where set_id = X. In this list I want to show name of subinventory and item. Thats why the WHERE is mandatory (I believe so)

Comment: For view it's necessary, you don't need dataProvider there, you can loop through `setDetail`. Updated answer.

Comment: Yes, but for each setDetail.* I'll do, it'll make a sql request, if I have 100 rows with 5 column it makes 500 request, thats a bit too much is'nt ?

Comment: @eephyne Nope, your database request is 0 because of eager loading, secondary this is matter of representation so , you can use dataProvider or Loop, it's upto your requirement. If you are expecting numerous records then go with dataProvider.